# Where is the plugin folder for Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, android-studio, intellij-plugin

I have installed a plugin which now crashes my Android Studio on start. Does someone know where Android Studio stores its downloaded plugin files, so I can delete it manually?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Android Studio plugin directories are `/Applications/Android Studio.app/plugins` and `~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview`(hidden). Perhaps if you find and delete the bad plugin folder Android Studio will be able to be started correctly.

Comment: Ah, the ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview folder did the trick. Plugins are stored there as own folders. I was looking at the wrong place under /Library/Application Support/
Now AS starts again, thanks.

Comment: I found them in ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio1.3

Comment: For AndroidStudio4.1 ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Comment: For Android Studio 4.2 ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/plugins

Answer (score 25):

For **Android Studio 4.1** main folder was change location

Now main folder you can find in path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer !

Answer (score 15):

This is where I could able to delete the plugin which was showing errors whenever I open Android Studio due to plugin incompatibility. even after error I could able to work. But still, I deleted the plugin. After that no error.

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins
```

Comment: The only helpful answer, you deserve the tick.

Answer (score 9):

For Android Studio 1.4, check the following folder:

```
~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio1.4
```

Answer (score 5):

For Android Studio 4.1.1 the path is:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/
```

Answer (score 4):

For Android Studio 2.3 its:

> /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/templates

Answer (score 1):

For android studio 4.0 goto Application then right click and choose 'show package Contents'

Answer (score 1):

As for Mac Os:
Android Studio plugin directories are /Applications/Android Studio.app/plugins and ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudioPreview(hidden). Perhaps if you find and delete the bad plugin folder Android Studio will be able to be started correctly.

As for Windows:
go to : C:\Users%yourUserName%\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

delete plugin at What do you expect the problem from.

Answer (score 0):

```
~/Library/Application Support/<PRODUCT><VERSION>
```

Based on the official documentation:

Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and log:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Answer (score 0):

~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio2022.1/disabled_plugins.txt

Answer (score -1):

just uninstall Android Studio and Again Install Android Studio your plugin problem is solve bcz some file in setting automatically hidden and u can not access these files so plz just reinstall Android Studio

Comment: this is better off as a comment. Try to make answers to questions that don't need comments

Answer (score -1):

Click on android studio label, select preferences from spinner items.

[image]

1. Click on android studio label
2. Select preferences tab from drop down
3. Here you find the screen where you can find option plugin