# Plugin Folder of Android Studio in Linux

Tags: linux, android-studio, intellij-idea

Does someone know where Android Studio stores its downloaded plugin files in Linux OS ? Manually i need to delete a plugin.
[Found solution for Mac users here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23537455/5515371)

Comment: I've installed Android Studio in `/opt/android-studio` and I have plugins in `/opt/android-studio/plugins/` on Ubuntu

Comment: @asclepix I have not installed Android Studio.I will open using androidstudio/bin/ ./studio.sh

Comment: So, look for androidstudio/plugins/

Answer (score 14):

With the new version of Android studio (4.1) some plugins are compatible with IntelliJ IDEA only.
I had some issues in delete the plugins not compatible from Android Studio so I solved the problem looking in my File Manager.

I located the unsupported plugins in

```
/home/**YOUR_USERNAME**/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/
```

I deleted the JAR files and the issue was solved.

Some other pluging anyway could create other issues and Android Studio ask us if we want to report them to Google. Deleting the plugins files or Folders, as above,this issue was solved too.

Comment: I'm on Windows and can't find the versioned directory in Users/*username*/. There is only a .android directory there.

Comment: @Asim for windos go to this directory : C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins

Answer (score 4):

If you used Jetbrains Toolbox to install Android Studio, it should be located at:
`~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/AndroidStudio`

Answer (score 3):

You can find it at:

```
/home/**YOUR_USERNAME**/.AndroidStudio2.2/config/plugins
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Ubuntu users**

1. go to `home`
2. press `ctrl+h` to show hidden folder `.local`
3. now go to `.local` folder
4. you will find the `share` folder, go inside the `share` folder
5. Find `Google` and go to the `Android Studio 4.1` folder and you can see all the plugin folders you have added to your Android Studio.