# 'Plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)'

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, sceneform

I am getting an error **Plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)"** is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)**. I installed Google Sceneform Tools (Beta) plugin from plugins and after restarting the error stated above is shown. I am currently using Android Studio 4.1

Comment: My problem is that I cannot make the error go away: if I go to Settings > Plugins its not listed in there. Same with the Fabric plugin.

Answer (score 13):

TL;DR: to make the error message go away I'd suggest to manually remove the plugin because it's not listed in the installed plugin list (possibly due to the error). To do that you need to navigate to the plugin folder and delete the directory of the Sceneform plugin. The folder location is operating system dependent, assuming here that the Android Studio version is 4.1:

- For **Windows**: `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Google` or also check `C:\Users\{USER}\.AndroidStudio4.1\config\plugins`
- For **MacOS**: `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins/` (you may check out `~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio/marketplace` or other places for older versions, see [Where is the plugin folder for Android Studio on MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537065/where-is-the-plugin-folder-for-android-studio-on-mac))
- For **Linux**: `~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/`

---

Update: here is maintained successor of the Google Sceneform source code advised by Romain Guy: https://twitter.com/romainguy/status/1371864003882807300?s=03 https://github.com/ThomasGorisse/sceneform-android-sdk

---

Adding to @GokulDAS027's answer (that the plugin is deprecated) you can also see that the `Sceneform` Github repo (https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/) is archived. Now you have to basically make `sceneformsrc` and `sceneformux` directories part of your project. See my blog post: https://csaba.page/blog/sceneform-breaking-change.html. Or just follow the archived Sceneform repository's README. One gotcha is that if you start recently you probably have an `AndroidX` project, and you need to upgrade Sceneform's source code to `AndroidX`. You can fish among the forks of the archived repository. Many people perform some code re-styling and refactoring, while I did just the necessary changes, you are welcome to just copy those two directories from the https://github.com/CsabaConsulting/ARPhysics repository.

Sceneform is an abstraction layer over ARCore. It offers great things like `TransformableNode` or a notch higher level abstractions than ARCore. It's up to you to decide if it offers enough features that you embrace it as a whole, or maybe you'll cherry pick. One thing you won't have though is the plugin. As we saw that provided some sfa/sfb compilation tooling and visualization panes for those objects in Android Studio. @GokulDAS027 mentions that you can use more standard formats for your models now.

Comment: Without sceneform in the plugins we can't view anymore the .glb at design time.

Comment: @jake That's correct. I guess the only solution in this case is to revert to an older version of Android Studio and install the plugin manually. Then somehow convert the sfa into some other native format.

Comment: I included a module from GitHub <https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk> and use the same steps as suggested but getting an error at "import android.support.annotation.Nullable;"

I understood that I need to upgrade Sceneform's source code to **androidx** but how to do this I am facing difficulties.

Please suggest

Comment: @shri120kant try `import androidx.annotation.Nullable`. If you are uncertain of an androidx import look up the corresponding file's imports and lines in https://github.com/CsabaConsulting/ARPhysics/tree/master/sceneformsrc and https://github.com/CsabaConsulting/ARPhysics/tree/master/sceneformux

Comment: @CsabaToth I'm getting the below errors which are not available in androidx      import android.media.Image;
import android.support.annotation.VisibleForTesting;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
what possible solution can I use here

Comment: @shri120kant Take the two folders I mentioned in my recent comments. You also need to check and adjust dependencies and their versions in your build gradle and a few more bits possibly. Please open a StackOverflow entry specifying the details, the most helpful would be if you reference your Git repo so I can look at it.

Comment: @shri120kant Once you phrase the SO post please link it here so I can take a look.

Answer (score 5):

Google has **deprecated** the Sceneform library earlier this year. But since the library itself was opensourced, we can still use and modify it. But can't expect support for the plugin.

The plugin was intended to help loading `.sfb`(3d file format for Sceneform) but later, this format was ditched and started supporting the standard GLB, glTF, Obj and other formats. So probably you won't need the plugin anymore.
Also, loading GLB is easy, just place it in the assets folder and load it in

```
ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(context, Uri.parse(ASSET_LOC))
        ...
```

Comment: That's useful info. The plugin I think wasn't just about loading the SFB, but also compiling the SFB from SFA, and I think also some display view and stuff. The whole Sceneform Github repo went into archived state. My problem is that I cannot make the error go away: if I go to Settings > Plugins its not listed in there.

Comment: Ooh that's strange, maybe try finding it in market place, install it and then uninstall..
I had uninstalled it long before, so don't know about current situation.

Comment: I ended up finding the directory on my Linux box and manually deleting the two plugins...

Comment: @CsabaToth I have the same scenario that I cannot install the plugin Sceneform, but what exactly do you mean by deleting the two plugins in my android studio plugins directory? And how do I install it? I am new to ARCore with SceneForm

Comment: And since they decided to deprecate it what would be the alternatives?

Comment: @jake Read my answer, I added a section addressing Sceneform.

Comment: @GokulDAS027 without the plugins we cant view the .glb at design time.

Comment: @jake The only way to get SceneForm plugins work is to go back in time (possibly with a virtual environment so you wouldn't collide with your fresh stuff) and install an older Android Studio + manually install the SceneForm plugins from backups.

Answer (score 2):

To make the error go away after Android Studio updation,

Just go to this path

- **For windows** - C:\Users\User Name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins
- **For Linux** - ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins

You can see all the installed plugins' folders and there you have to delete the sceneform folder.